# How to Increase the length of column type geometry in postgres(pgAdminIII)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spherical-geometry

I am just wondering is there any way to increase the default length of column type geometry in postgres.

Since we are trying to save large number of vertices polygon in to the geometry column geom in postgres database.It is saving nothing.

Comment: There is no practical limit on the size of geometries in Postgres/Postgis, and you don't set them with DDL statements, see this [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/about/), ie, you decare a type to be of type Geometry, optionally setting the projection and geometry type (Point, Line, Polygon, etc). There is no equivalent of int, char(30), bit, serial, it is just a geometry. It is likely your issue is elsewhere, but impossible to discern from the information you have provided.

Comment: Actually, technically it is a BLOB, but same point holds.